как в блокноте notepad++ дополнить строку до нужного количества символов
есть
abc
ab
abcdf

нужно получить
00000abc
000000ab
000abcdf

как это сделать с помощью регулярок, или любой другой способ

Если мы хотим выровнять по 8 символов и нет строки длиннее 8 символов
исходный:
abc
ab
abcdf

Добавляем во все строки 8 "0", через рег.выражение найти ^, заменить 00000000, получаем:
00000000abc
00000000ab
00000000abcdf

Убираем лишнее Найти ^.*(.{8})$ заменить \1
получаем:
00000abc
000000ab
000abcdf


чотка) yyyyyyyz
